# How to change orientation vertical to horizontal in PDF with Prawnto_2 Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawnto

I use prawnto_2 gem for generate PDF file in Rails 4. In my controller, I only send params for render in my PDF file.

My gemfile have:

```
#some gems
gem "prawnto_2", :require => "prawnto"
```

So, in my views folder I have a file with extension **.pdf.prawn**

An example of my code I use is:

```
class PdfFilesController < ApplicationController
def user_car_pdf
    @users = User.all
    @car = User.find(params[:id]).car
end

#In user_car_pdf.pdf.prawn

text "User's Car - #{@car.id.to_s.rjust(5, '0')}", :align => :center
move_down 3

@users.each do |data|
  text "#{data.name}# / #{data.email}"
  text "#{data.description}"
end
```

But, I have a enormous table with much information. So, the vertical orientation is not a option, I need change the orientation.

How I can do that? I have researched and can not find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:page_layout => :landscape according to the prawnto_2 gem documentation

class PdfFilesController < ApplicationController
  prawnto :prawn => { :page_size => 'A4', :page_layout => :landscape }
end
```

Comment: Where do I put that line? Or how do I use it correctly? Because I also found this solution but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Updated, again from the documentation

Comment: Ok It's works but that line makes the PDF download. In the beginning, the pdf is displayed in the browser. Still, already got what I wanted. Thanks, I need to read better the documentation.

Comment: Set `:inline => true` after prawnto (I think), though it should default to this.

Comment: Link to documentation would have been nice

Comment: @fkoessler it's not hard to find.